# Content Security Policy nodejs program

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy

I am developing a site and I have a problem with the Content Security Policy. It is triggered when I try to retrieve images from my DB for example or when I want to retrieve my font from google...

Here is the github link of the project: https://github.com/BaptisteHardelin/Cocktail-bar

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a policy in a meta tag here: https://github.com/BaptisteHardelin/Cocktail-bar/blob/d7f11ec45f4c479f77ef5d9ac1d77bdf8aa5cee2/views/partials/header.ejs

However, your policy sets img-src and the browser console says you don't. The most likely explanation is that something sets another policy in a response header with "default-src 'none'". You will need to disable the other policy or move your own policy there. Then your image will likely show and you need to add that google domain for the font (fonts.gstatic.com?) to font-src.

Comment: Hello Halvor thanks for your response :) I understood what was wrong thanks to you, but I have no idea how to fix it because in my code there is nothing that says "default-src 'none'"

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found my policy and it'is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *; img-src * data: blob: android-webview-video-poster:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">` thanks for your help

Comment: Hey, this is more like a comment than that it is an answer. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer